# RTC (Rational Team Concert) integration with XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, rtc

Is there any way to integrate IBM RTC to XCode. Officially I think its not supporting only by Command line we can achieve the goal. So is there any other way, can I use source tree with RTC.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/197830/rtc-plugin-for-xcode?cm_mc_uid=10383560648314514629463&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1451462946)

> I don't believe there is an official plug-in for XCode but here is a set of articles written describing how to use RTC and XCode together:

- "[Using Rational Team Concert on Mac with Xcode (Part 1)](https://jazz.net/library/article/979)"
- "[Using Rational Team Concert on Mac with Xcode (Part 2)](https://jazz.net/library/article/980)"
- "[Using Rational Team Concert on Mac with Xcode (Part 3)](https://jazz.net/library/article/981)"